# SpringBatch : How to not have an error if a line is greater than my last range?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Using a FixedLengthTokenizer in reader, I manage to get my fields by positions :

```
.lineTokenizer(new FixedLengthTokenizer()  {{ setNames("firstName", "lastName", "age'"); setColumns(new Range(1,4), new Range(5,6),new Range(7-9)); }})
```

However, I have an error if the line is longer than 9.
I can't set "new Range(7)" because I don't wan't the end of the line.
I only want the 7-9 positions even if the line is longer.

How to solve my problem ?

Regards.

**ANSWER :**

```
.lineTokenizer(new FixedLengthTokenizer()  {{ setNames("firstName", "lastName", "age'"); setColumns(new Range(1,4), new Range(5,6),new Range(7-9)); setStrict(false); }})
```

Comment: Have you tried `setStrict(false)`? Otherwise you might need a custom tokenizer.

Comment: I had seen setStrict but I didn't understand how to use it in my case.
Thanks to your response, I understood. Thanks a lot.